Revert Windows state after GPO application
Couldn't find a clear and consolidated article on the "official" way to do this.
Is there a definitive way to revert all the changes that a given GPO will apply to a computer after applying it for the first time ?
This is to prevent GPO tatooing which is a use case where some settings persists on the system even after disabling/unliking the GPO.
Thank you,

This is a good question, as it's something talked a lot, but the fact Microsoft is moving away from onprem to more Intune/Endpoint Manager policy make me think it's a problem sysadmin will die with it in the long term.

No. A Group Policy can have many settings that are far beyond the reversible administrative template settings. There isn't a mechanism to reverse or undo these settings, or even know what settings may have been changed.

I understand what you're saying, but in the case of a more generic GPO, such as a Hardening policy (CIS/Security Baselines etc.), a majority of the settings involved are registry keys. I'm surprised there isn't a way to take a snapshot of the system state and go back to it.

@Segfault: there is a way to take a snapshot, but that is completely separate from Group Policy.
